# Get implicit center value Titanium

Tags: ios, label, titanium, center

I have created a label in the following code. Now I would like to get the current center coordinates of the label without explicitly setting the center.

How can I do that ?

```
var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({width:400, height:400});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until the view has been laid out, so set a listener for the [`postlayout`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-event-postlayout) event, and then use the updated [`rect`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-rect) values to calculate the center.

```
label.addEventListener('postlayout', function(e) {
    // Calculate the center using the RO rect property
    var center = {
        x : rect.x + rect.width / 2,
        y : rect.y + rect.height / 2
    };
    // Do what you ned to do with that....
});
```